# C# Parallel loop local variable thread safe Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

My question is little theoretical I want to know whether `List<object>` is thread-safe if I used `Parallel.For` in this way. Please see below:

```
public static List<uint> AllPrimesParallelAggregated(uint from, uint to)
        {
            List<uint> result = new List<uint>();
            Parallel.For((int)from, (int)to,
                () => new List<uint>(), // Local state initializer
                (i, pls, local) =>      // Loop body
                {
                    if (IsPrime((uint)i))
                    {
                        local.Add((uint)i);
                    }
                    return local;
                },
                local =>                // Local to global state combiner
                {
                    lock (result)
                    {
                        result.AddRange(local);
                    }
                });
            return result;
        }
```

Is `local` list is thread safe? Whether I've the correct data in `result` list without data is being alter due to multiple threads as using I'm having normal loop?

**Note:** I'm not worry about list order. I want to know about length of the list and data.

Comment: `List` is not Parallel thread safe, especially how you intend.

Comment: So, its mean my `result` list will not have the same data as I can get from the normal loop?

Comment: it means ..... `List` is not thread safe !!

Comment: It should be rather unlikely that the order of numbers in result is always the same or the same as if you had run it single threaded. Since you ``lock(result)`` and since ``local`` is the result of an asynchronous operation, your combiner function should work.

Comment: Ok. I understand order will not same as run it single thread. But how about  list count?

Comment: list it self is not thread safe. how ever since `local.Add` is used only by one thread there should not be a problem. after `Parallel.For` you should order your list again. `result.OrderBy(I => I).ToList()`

Comment: @Saadi The length of the list should be the same as if computed single threaded. Maybe the single threaded version would be faster, even as you create a new list for each single prime number. You would rather want to have the tasks compute ranges of prims and then combine those sub-ranges eventually. Hm... no idea if that last statement of mine is correct. Depends on how that parallel thing works.

Comment: @BitTickler, can you please share a brief answer so that the viewer know the answer of it. Thanks!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, So, you are telling me that there will be one thread in // Loop body section

Comment: How about a bit of Parallel LINQ, which manages all of the collation of results for you. Then, it's as easy as: `Enumerable.Range(from, to-from).AsParallel().Where(i => IsPrime((uint)i)).ToList()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this solution thread-safe?  Technically yes, in reality no.

The very notion of a thread-safe `List` (as opposed to a queue or a bag) is that the list is safe with respect to *order*, or, more strictly, *index*, since there is no key other than an ascending integer. In a parallel world, it's sort of a nonsensical concept, when you think about it.  That is why the [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace contains a `ConcurrentBag` and a `ConcurrentQueue` but no `ConcurrentList`.

Since you are asking about the thread safety of a list, I am assuming the requirement for your software is to generate a list that is in ascending order.  If that is the case, no, your solution will not work.  While the code is technically thread-safe, the threads may finish in any order and your variable `result` will end up non-sorted.

If you wish to use parallel computation, you must store your results in a bag, then when all threads are finished sort the bag to generate the ordered list.   Otherwise you must perform the computation in series.

And since you have to use a bag anyway, you may as well use [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx), and then you won't have to bother with the `lock{}` statement.

Comment: Yep. A `ConcurrentBag` would probably feature in my solution if I didn't prefer PLINQ for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

List Is not thread safe. but your current algorithm works. as it was explained in other answer and comments.

This is the description about localInit of For.Parallel

> The `<paramref name="localInit"/>` delegate is **invoked once for each thread** that participates in the loop's execution and returns the initial local state for each of those threads.  These initial states are passed to the first

---

IMO You are adding unnecessary complexity inside your loop. I would use `ConcurrentBag` instead. which is thread safe by design.

```
ConcurrentBag<uint> result = new ConcurrentBag<uint>();
Parallel.For((long) from, (long) to,
    (i, PLS) =>
    {
        if (IsPrime((uint)i))
        {
            result.Add((uint)i); // this is thread safe. don't worry
        }
    });
return result.OrderBy(I => I).ToList(); // order if that matters
```

[See concurrent bag here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx)

> All public and protected members of ConcurrentBag are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my question is everyone is saying that List isn't thread safe. How can you say that `result.Add((uint)i);` is thread safe?

Comment: this is ConcurrentBag. not a list. ConcurrentBag is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

A `List<T>` is not thread-safe. For the way you are using it, thread safety is not required though. You need thread safety when you access a resource concurrently from multiple threads. You are not doing that, since you are working on local lists.

At the end you are adding the contents of the local lists into the `result` variable. Since you use `lock` for this operation, you are thread-safe within that block.

So your solution is probably fine.